# Can the default value of the LAG() function be a column expression, or should it always be a literal value?

Tags: window-functions, lag

Should the 'default' value of the LAG() be a literal value or can it be a column expression as in the below example?

select LAG(column, 1, column) over (Order by column) from table;

Answer (score 0):

not sure where you are running the LAG function, but in BigQuery as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag) the default value needs to be a constant.

In case you want a dynamic value though, you can try using COALESCE which should fill the null generated by the missing previous row.